OpenSuse Leap Micro 6.0 error to refresh repository Problem retrieving files from 'repo-main (6.0)'
please help me to solve this issue.
I installed opensuse leap micro 6.0 on my virtual machine.
when I want to install git, it show error. then, I tried to refresh my repo. I got this error
sudo zypper ref
[sudo] password for root: 
Problem retrieving files from 'repo-main (6.0)'.
Download (curl) error for 'http://cdn.opensuse.org/distribution/leap-micro/6.0/product/repo/openSUSE-Leap-Micro-6.0-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml':
Error code: Connection failed Curl error (6)
Error message: Could not resolve host: cdn.opensuse.org

Please see the above error message for a hint.
Skipping repository 'repo-main (6.0)' because of the above error.
Could not refresh the repositories because of errors.

Please help me.
thank you.
I tried to refresh, reboot and do curl on cdn. but it can't to curl.
curl http://cdn.opensuse.org/distribution/leap-micro/6.0/product/repo/openSUSE-Leap-Micro-6.0-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: cdn.opensuse.org

